# SQL Server update query extremely slow

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update, subquery, query-optimization

I want to a simple update statement on a table with c.200m records. However, it seems to be taking ages.

```
UPDATE a
SET hybrid_trade_flag = CASE WHEN b.trade_id IS NOT NULL THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END
FROM [tbl_master_trades] a
LEFT JOIN [tbl_hybrid_trades_subset] b
    ON a.trade_id = b.trade_id
```

The 1st table `tbl_master_trades` has c.200m records and has an index created on `trade_id` and another column (together). The 2nd table `tbl_hybrid_trades_subset` has around 200k. This query ran for over 40 mins before I had to cancel it (cancellation itself took around 30 min).

I thought maybe converting the 2nd table into a temp table and splitting the statement would help, so converted it into the following:

```
UPDATE a
SET hybrid_trade_flag = 'Y'
FROM [tbl_master_trades] a
INNER JOIN #tmp_hybrid_trades b
    ON a.trade_id = b.trade_id

UPDATE a
SET hybrid_trade_flag = 'N'
FROM [tbl_master_trades] a
WHERE hybrid_trade_flag IS NULL
```

Even above two queries took 30 min to run. I need to run several such updates (c.80) on the 1st table, so I'm not sure if this is viable as it would take days! Can someone please advise on if/how I can speed this up?

Comment: Does hybrid_trade_flag actually need to be updated for every row or does it just need to be refreshed based on the logic you posted? It might be more efficient to break the update into separate statements and include the appropriate filter in the where clause to avoid pointless updates.

Comment: It needs to be set to 'Y' for where the trade exists in the hybrid table and 'N' for everything else

Comment: @Chipmunk_da . . . Updating 200 million rows is going to take just this side of forever.  Perhaps you could set the default value to "N" and just change the subquery to "Y".

Comment: @GordonLinoff That's a good idea! I'll do that. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would start by rewriting the query to use `exists`:

```
update t
set hybrid_trade_flag = case 
    when exists(select 1 from tbl_hybrid_trades_subset ts where ts.trade_id = t.trade_id)
    then 'Y'
    else 'N'
end
from tbl_master_trades t
```

Then, I would recommend an index on `tbl_hybrid_trades_subset(trade_id)` so the subquery can execute quickly.

An index on `tbl_master_trades(trade_id)` might also help (without any other column in the index), but the index on the table that the subquery addresses seems more important.

That said, 200M rows is still a large number of rows to proceed, so the query will probably take quite a lot of time anyway.

Comment: Thanks @GMB! I'll try your suggestions, hopefully it reduces the execution time

Comment: qq - I'll be performing some updates on the master table without joining to any other table. Would it help if create an index on every column that I'll be using in the `where` clause for those `update` statements?

Answer (score 1):

You're running into 2 problems

- you're checking the existence of c.200m values in another table
- you're updating c.200m values in the base table

To work around this you can

- add the appropriate index to the lookup table
- avoid updating where not strictly needed

The index in question would be

```
CREATE INDEX idx_trade_id ON tbl_hybrid_trades_subset (trade_id)
```

To limit the amount of updates use this:

```
UPDATE a
   SET hybrid_trade_flag = CASE WHEN b.trade_id IS NOT NULL THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END
  FROM [tbl_master_trades] a
  LEFT OUTER JOIN [tbl_hybrid_trades_subset] b
               ON b.trade_id = a.trade_id
 WHERE hybrid_trade_flag != CASE WHEN b.trade_id IS NOT NULL THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END
```

The first time might still take a while but subsequent updates should be quite a bit faster.